# Presentation Error на 10 тесте python

Tags: python, python-3.x, теория-чисел

Пытаюсь решить следующую задачу в яндекс контесте

*В этой задаче вам нужно вычислить значение функции Эйлера от некоторого биномиального коэффициента  («выбрать k элементов из n»).*

**Формат ввода**
*В единственной строке записаны два целых числа k и n (0 ≤ k ≤ n ≤ 500 000).*

**Формат вывода**
*Выведите одно число  по модулю 1 000 000 007.*

**Пример**

Ввод |Вывод

1 4   |5

0 2   |1

5 10  |72

9 тестов проходит нормально, а на 10 вылетает presentation error. Что вообще может происходить?

Идея следующая,при подсчёте сочетания, раскладываю все элементы факториала в числителе и знаменителе на простые множители. И по ним уже считаю функцию Эйлера.

```
from collections import Counter
#разложение на простые множители
def simple_div(a):
    c=[2,3,5]
    in_dict={}
    in_list=[]
    k=0
    simp_av=make_list(a)
    while (a>1):
        if (a%c[k]==0):
            a=a/c[k]
            if (c[k] in in_dict.keys()):
                in_dict[c[k]]=in_dict[c[k]]+1
                in_list.append(c[k])
            else:
                in_dict[c[k]]=1
                in_list.append(c[k])
        else:
            
            k+=1
            if (k>len(c)-1):
                simp_av,b=next_simple(c[-1],simp_av)
                c.append(b)
                
                
    return in_list

# функция для подсчет суммы цифр в числе
def sumc(a):
    b=str(a)
    c=0
    for x in b:
        c+=int(x)
    return c
#формирование списка, которые не содержит числа кратные 2,3 и 5
def make_list(a):
    c=[2,3,5]
    for i in range (6,a+1):
        if ((int(str(i)[-1])!=0) & (int(str(i)[-1])%2!=0) & (sumc(i)%3!=0) & (int(str(i)[-1])!=5)):
                c.append(i)
    return c


# ищет следующее простое число после заданного, а также удаляет в списке со всеми числами все числа кратные ему
def next_simple(c,arr1):
    arr=arr1
    b=arr[arr1.index(c)+1]
    values_rem=[]
    if (arr[arr1.index(c)+1]**2>arr[-1]):
        return arr, b
    else:
        for i in range(arr.index(arr[arr1.index(c)+1]**2), len(arr)-1):
            if(arr[i]%b==0):
                values_rem.append(arr[i])
            else:
                continue
        if (len(values_rem)!=0):
            for value in values_rem:
                arr.remove(value)
        return arr, b
 

# представление сочетания как список простых множителей
def sochet(k,n):
    cis=[]
    znam=[]
    if (k>=(n-k)):
        cis=[simple_div(i) for i in range(k+1,n+1)]
        znam=[simple_div(i) for i in range(1,(n-k)+1)]
    else:
        cis=[simple_div(i) for i in range(n-k+1,n+1)]
        znam=[simple_div(i) for i in range(1,k+1)]
    
    cis_sim=[]  
    for x in cis:
         cis_sim+=x
    znam_sim=[]  
    for x in znam:
         znam_sim+=x    
    c=dict(Counter(cis_sim))
    z=dict(Counter(znam_sim))
    in_set=set(c.keys()).intersection(set(z.keys()))
    c_after=c.copy()
    for k in in_set:
        n=c[k]-z[k]
        if(n>0):
            c_after[k]=n
        else:
            del(c_after[k])
    
    return c_after
    
#Расчет функции Эйлера
def Eyler(div):
    mul=1
    for key,value in(div.items()):
        mul=mul*(pow(key,(value-1))*(key-1))
    return mul

tmp=input().split(' ')
k=int(tmp[0])
n=int(tmp[1])
a=(sochet(k,n))
print(Eyler(a))
```

Answer (score 3):

На первый взгляд задача решена верно. Упущено что результат должен быть по модулю 10<sup>9</sup> + 7. Вероятно ваша программа в ответе печатает столь большое число, что проверяющая система не способна его прочитать (`Presentation error`).

**P.S.** Замечание по идее алгоритма.

> Идея следующая,при подсчёте сочетания, раскладываю все элементы
> факториала в числителе и знаменителе на простые множители. И по ним
> уже считаю функцию Эйлера.

[Разложение факториала на простые множители](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8) можно вычислить без разложения его множителей. Функция `factorial_exponent` считает степень простого `p` в разложении `n!`:

```
def factorial_exponent(n, p):
    # assert is_prime(p)
    e = 0
    t = n // p
    while t > 0:
        e += t
        t //= p
    return e
```

`binomial_exponent` считает степень простого `p` в биномиальном коэффициенте для `n, k`.

```
def binomial_exponent(n, k, p):
    return factorial_exponent(n, p) - \
           (factorial_exponent(k, p) + factorial_exponent(n - k, p))
```

[Функция Эйлера φ(n)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) от биномиального коэффициента считается по его разложению. `primes` - перечисляет простые числа в заданом диапазонe:

```
def phi_cnk(n, k):
    phi = 1
    for p in primes(n + 1):
        e = binomial_exponent(n, k, p)
        if e > 0:
            phi *= (p - 1) * p ** (e - 1)
    return phi
```

Если вы заботитесь о скорости, во время расчёта φ(n) все умножения и возведения в степень надо делать по модулю. Но и без этого φ(Cnk(500000, 250000)) считается меньше чем за секунду.

**P.P.S.** Код для получения простых чисел сложнее чем нужно. [Решето Эратосфена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0) в условиях задачи займёт пол мегабайта памяти и найдёт простые почти мгновенно:

```
def primes(n):
    if n >= 2:
        sieve = bytearray(n)
        sieve[:2] = 1, 1
        for i in range(math.isqrt(n - 1) + 1):
            if sieve[i] == 0:
                for j in range(i * i, n, i):
                    sieve[j] = 1
        for i in range(n):
            if sieve[i] == 0:
                yield i
```